# MALFORMED_REQUEST: "Incoming JSON request does not map to API request" with Paypal integration in salesforce

Tags: json, paypal, salesforce, payment

I am doing paypal integration in my salesforce account, but am getting a validation error when doing payment through Rest API call: `Incoming JSON request does not map to API request`

I have tried the below link sample json values:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment

Share the correct json values for payment, or assist me on how to proceed.

Please find the apex code for payment:

```
public void Fetchcredentail(){
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse response;
            response = new HttpResponse();
            response.setBody(convertJsonBody());
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment');
            req.setMethod('POST');
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer <Access token>');
            response  = http.send(req);
            system.debug(response+'-------'+response.getBody());
}   
public string convertJsonBody(){

        string json=        '{'+
    '  "intent": "sale",'+
    '  "payer": {'+
    '    "payment_method": "credit_card",'+
    '    "funding_instruments": [{'+
    '      "credit_card": {'+
    '        "number": "4417119669820331",'+
    '        "type": "visa",'+
    '        "expire_month": 11,'+
    '        "expire_year": 2018,'+
    '        "cvv2": "874",'+
    '        "first_name": "Venkat",'+
    '        "last_name": "H",'+
    '        "billing_address": {'+
    '          "line1": "111 First Street",'+
    '          "city": "Chennai",'+
    '          "state": "TN",'+
    '          "postal_code": "6000088",'+
    '          "country_code": "IN"'+
    '        }'+
    '      }'+
    '    }]'+
    '  },'+
    '  "transactions": [{'+
    '    "amount": {'+
    '      "total": "1.47",'+
    '      "currency": "USD",'+
    '      "details": {'+
    '        "subtotal": "1.41",'+
    '        "tax": "0.03",'+
    '        "shipping": "0.03"'+
    '      }'+
    '    },'+
    '    "description": "The payment transaction description."'+
    '  }]'+
    '}';
    return json;
}
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  then edit your question so that we may help.  Specifically, you need to include all relevant code *within the body of the question* so that if the link disappears, the question will still be valid and useful.  Also, we are just users like you, and don't want to go running all over the web just to find out what your question is -- before we do the work to find the answer for you.  Including everything we need to know right here will increase your chances of receiving an answer.

Comment: The above content is enough for finding the solution, so could you help me to find the solution for the above?